# Finding the longest permutation of 1 ... k within an array?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

It's given a sequence of N integer numbers. How to find the lenght of longest subsequence of adjacent numbers which form a permutation. I have only found O(N^2) algorithm. I think there should be O(NlogN) or even O(N) solutions. Please suggest any of them.

Answer of this sequence `1 3 1 2 5` is 3 (4 1 **3 1 2** 5 )

This is SPOJ problem [LPERMUT](https://www.spoj.com/problems/LPERMUT/).

O(N^2) algorithm

```
Foreach i find the sum of first i elemetns: Sum(i)

Foreach i find the last element with indexes 1 .. i-1 which is equal to i-rd element: Prev(i)

Foreach i iterate j throw i+1 .. N while Prev(j) equals between i and j. 
//So we get that all elemnent between i and j are distinct. 

Then check if sum of them is equal to 1+2+...(j-i+1). 
    If it occurs that elements are permutation. 
    Sum of the elements between i and j we can get by Sum(j) - Sum(i-1)
```

Comment: Can you post your O(N^2) solution?

Comment: Well, why do you believe that there's an O(n log n) solution?  Permutation alone is n!.

Comment: @Makoto I dont need to check all permutation which are n!. My solution gets Time limit exceeded on SPOJ, so I think there must be a better appreoach. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: @SergeyS - No, I haven't found anything

Answer (score -2):

You can use a greedy algorithm

```
Input: ListOfElements={el_1, el_2,...,el_N}
permutation<-{}
while(dimension(size(permutation)<DesiredSize)
{
  while(VerifyIfIsPermutation(permutation U el)=false)
   el<-SelectAnElementFromList(ListOfElements)
}
print permutation
```

This algorithm have O(n^2) complexity. You can reduce this complexity if previously sorted array.
Another method to generate permutation is to use a random shuffle for this list. Also, You can use a number of rotations between elements, thus guaranteeing that the resulting permutations are not repeated.

Comment: I dont need to generate a permutation. Permutation is in the the given sequence. I need to find it.

Comment: I don't think that this answer's the OP's question.  The OP wants to find the longest subarray in the original array that is a permutation, not to generate all permutations of a certain length.

Comment: This algorithm is very easy. You can put the condition that dimension of generated permutation to be equal with the dimension of list. This condition is guaranteed for rotation algorithm type.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?  I honestly don't see how you can use a permutation generator to find the longest permutation embedded in an array.

Comment: If you use for input a some vector will have to eliminate repeated elements and after that you obtain a list of unique elements. This list provided the largest dimension of the permutation.